# Craft installer errors

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install craft on my local machine (OSX Mavericks). It gets stuck on a screen with "Oops." and a spinning icon.

The requirements checker says all is good. I have InnoDB and MySQL 5.7.3 installed. I get a list of errors in craft.log:

```
2014/09/22 15:40:54 [warning] [application] Skipping record /Library/WebServer/Documents/lays2/craft/app/records/BaseRecord.php because it’s abstract or an interface.

2014/09/22 15:40:55 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::execute() failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1171 All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead. The SQL statement executed was: CREATE TABLE `craft_assetfolders` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NULL,
`parentId` INT(11) NULL,
`sourceId` INT(11) NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`path` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
`dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
`dateUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
`uid` CHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci.

2014/09/22 15:40:55 [error] [exception.CDbException] exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1171 All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/lays2/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:358
```

There's also a Stack Trace.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Per [Brad's recent update](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2663/45), this turned out to be a bug (which is now fixed). Closing as a "bug report".

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, they made a chance in MySQL 5.7 that's breaking Craft and you've found a bug.  We haven't done any 5.7 testing, since it's not officially released, yet, but I'll install it and do some verification and update this answer.

**Update:**

This was a bug in Craft when using MySQL 5.7 and has been fixed for the next ([post 2.2.2588](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2588)) release.